# How to use NSUserDefaults for creating the auto login settings for application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know this very regular question But i didn't get that's way ask here I hope people will me out .
I have application which have the login page .And when ever I login I get Token_ID from server .I get this TokenID with help of JSON.

But I want to add the **Auto Login** function to my application .For that My application look like this

1. It has the two text field (username and password)
2. one check box for auto login And login button

I need  when ever user click on the check box which is for auto login It must store TokenID in application and when I close my application .And start the application again It must not ask for login me again.It start the same application with same TokenID which I store  for that user not a new one .And if I click the log out button it must logout from application And release the TokenID from my application .And after that if start the application it must ask for login with out that it must not go further in application

For that I do R&D from two days .And I found that I must use the NSUserDefaults for storing the TokenID which I am getting at the time of login .I want know how can I store the TokenID
into application and How can check it out the user logout or not .And if user not logout it start the application.And if user logout than it must ask for login to start the application

OR is that any idea  please give And explain me 
Thank you

Comment: You can store the value even in separate plist file and also in NSUserDefaults. Both of them shall store given value in it and for next time it will read from it and modify the value if application has been closed with logout. Are you getting these scenario?

Comment: Can you explain more @iApple please how can i do that with example code

Comment: @Seega has posted a reference link about how to use NSUserDefaults. Let me know if you face any problem with it. http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/20/using_nsuserdefaults/ is one more easy way to understand about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First result at google for "NSUSerDefaults Example"](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults)

On logout just overwrite the keys with nil and check on starting of the app if the key is nil

Comment: Can it open the same user which which was login perviously

Comment: Every start of the app you load the NSUserDefaults, if they are empty no one was logged in.
after login you save the data of the user in the NSUserDefaults. Next time the app start you read the NSUserDefaults LIKE EVERY TIME an get the Userinformation. Don't see the Problem its so simple

Comment: And if the User logs off you delete the NSUserDefaults so he has to login the next time

Answer (score 0):

you can  **save username information**

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
 {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"username"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
 }
```

if you have username information on NSUserDefaults, you can **get your username information**

```
 -(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
 {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"username"];

    return val;
 }
```